# Can Windows auditing be used on the entire system?

Tags: windows, security

I'm in the process of creating a high-interaction honeypot using a Windows system and I need to audit every last little thing that happens on the honeypot.

I understand [this](https://blog.windowsnt.lv/2011/11/15/tracking-user-activity-english/) can be done on a single object such as a file or a folder, but I need to audit the entire system.

So do I create an audit for each and every directory on the system, or is there a way to audit the entire system?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable: Advanced Audit Policy > Global Object Access Auditing > File System.

However, this will generate a considerable amount of noise, and does not get 'every last little thing'. You may want to re-consider auditing all file system activity, and instead selectively audit some folders and combine Windows auditing with Microsoft Sysinternals Sysmon:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/sysmon

Sysmon provides:

- auditing for events not include in Windows auditing (DriverLoaded,Named Pipes, RawAccessRead, NetworkConnection, CreateRemoteThread, ProcessAccess, RegistryKey/Value create/modify/delete).
- finer granularity of control/filtering.
- more detail for forensic analysis, such as the process guid and parent process guid, and values for some data that is changed.

**How To go from responding to hunting with Sysinternals Sysmon**
https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=D026B4699190F1E6!2843&ithint=file%2cpptx&app=PowerPoint&authkey=!AMvCRTKB_V1J5ow

---

[image: Sysmon Events]

---

[image: Advanced Audit Policy > Global Object Access Auditing > File System.]

---

Audit file system global object access

This policy setting allows you to apply a comprehensive object access audit policy to every file and folder on the file system for a computer. 
Configuring this setting also allows you to demonstrate that every file and folder on the computer is monitored by an audit policy that is managed from a central location.

This setting applies a global system access control list (SACL) to every file and folder. 
If both a file or folder SACL and a global SACL are configured on a computer, the effective SACL is derived by combining the file or folder SACL and the global SACL. 
This means that an audit event is generated when an activity matches either the file or folder SACL or the global SACL.

To configure a global object access policy, you must select Define this policy setting and click Configure to add at least one user or group to the global SACL. 
You must also enable the Audit File System setting under Advanced Audit Policy Configuration\System Audit Policies\Object Access.

Volume: Depends on the effective SACL and the level of user activity.